# When does a service get created by dependency injection

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I have an angular service containing some init code in its constructor. When is this code called, i.e. when is the service created?

- Already when the service is provided in some module?
- Or not until the first component injects it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services):

> When Angular discovers that a component depends on a service, it first checks if the injector has any existing instances of that service. If a requested service instance doesn't yet exist, the injector makes one using the registered provider, and adds it to the injector before returning the service to Angular.
>
> When all requested services have been resolved and returned, Angular
> can call the component's constructor with those services as arguments.

So it seems that a service is only instantiated when it is needed the first time.

In fact Angular even recognizes if the service will never be used and remove it from the build if it is not needed (taken from [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#provide-the-heroservice) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules)).

#### Test it for yourself

An easy test to verify this would be to put `console.log`s in both a component and a service that it depends upon to see in which order the are called.

Answer (score 2):

Until the first component injects it, go throgh below link.

When Angular creates a new instance of a component class, it determines which services or other dependencies that component needs by looking at the constructor parameter types.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: I'm curious how Angular does this. It must determine at runtime the constructor parameter types, but as the constructor parameter types are known only to TypeScript at compile time, how does this compile to runtime conditional logic to put the right service in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If you reference on the module, the service run the constructor before components need,

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
  TestService],
 ...
})
```

If you reference on the component, the service create a new instance for the component

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-xpto',
  templateUrl: './xpto.html',
  providers:  [ TestService ]
})
```